# How to install the tools package that has Rdiff()

Tags: r

So I am trying to run this command in Rstudio to compare two files:

`Rdiff("C:/Users/twoodward/Documents/supplierdirectorytest/Supplier_Revised_Flatfiles (1)/SupplierData.csv","C:/Users/twoodward/Documents/supplierdirectorytest/Supplier_Revised_Flatfiles (1)/SupplierDataedited.csv" to, useDiff = FALSE, forEx = FALSE,
      nullPointers = TRUE, Log = TRUE)`

But for somereason it cant find the Rdiff() function, I know that the function exists in the ["tools"](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tools/versions/3.4.1) package, but can't find any documentation installing it?

Comment: post this as an answer and Ill give you the points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can explicitly call

```
tools::Rdiff(...)
```

or first run

```
library(tools)
Rdiff(...)
```